# Are there exist $a, b >0$ such that $az_1^Tz_1 \geq b|z_1^Tz_2|$ and $bz_2^Tz_2 \geq a|z_2^Tz_1|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, inequality

I am looking whether these inequalities can be held at the same time

$$az_1^Tz_1 \geq b|z_1^Tz_2| \\ bz_2^Tz_2 \geq a|z_2^Tz_1|,$$
where $a$ and $b$ are two positive constants, $z_i \in \mathbb{R}^2, z_i \neq 0$ and $z_1$ and $z_2$ are not parallel vectors.

If such constants do not exists, under what conditions in $z_i$ can be found? i.e. if they are orthogonal, then it is trivial.

This is what I have so far, fix $b = 1$ and take the absolute value of the dot product $|z_i^Tz_j| = ||z_i|| \,||z_j||\, |\cos\alpha|$

$$ 
a ||z_1|| \geq ||z_2||\,  |\cos\alpha| \\ ||z_2|| \geq a||z_1|| \, |\cos\alpha|,
$$
where $\alpha$ is the angle between the two vectors. Looking at the first inequality, if I choose $a > 0$ such that
$$
\frac{a}{|\cos\alpha|}||z_1|| \geq||z_2||,
$$
it turns out that (substituting in the second inequality)
$$
||z_1|| \geq ||z_1|| \cos^2\alpha,
$$
also I have the same relation for $z_2$. Does this mean that there exists such $a > 0$? I guess something is wrong in my computation, because I can not find $a$ explicitly.

Comment: I don't quite get what you're asking. Take $z_1$ orthogonal to $z_2$, both being non-zero, both your conditions are always satisfied.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy My question is that for two fixed non-parallel vectors, whether it is possible to compute such constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there does exist such an $a$ and $b$. As you did, fix $b=1$. You can rewrite your inequalities as the following 
\begin{align}
a|cos(\alpha)|\leq \frac{||z_2||}{||z_1||}\leq \frac{a}{|cos(\alpha)|}
\end{align}
Note that for any $a>0$
\begin{align}a|cos(\alpha)|\leq a \leq \frac{a}{|cos(\alpha)|}\end{align}
Clearly $a=\frac{||z_2||}{||z_1||}$ will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have such constants that the inequalities are true for all non-parallel vectors. Indeed, let's take $m=a/b>0$. We can take $z_2$ arbitrarily close to $z_1$ in direction and of arbitrary magnitude. Then we write

$$\frac{|(z_1,z_2)|}{\|z_1\|^2}\le m\le \frac{\|z_2\|^2}{|(z_1,z_2)|}.$$
By fixing $\|z_1\|=1$ and letting the direction of $z_2$ go to direction of $z_1$, we obtain that
$$ \| z_2 \|  \le m\le  \|z_2\|   .$$
Thus, $m=\|z_2\|$, which can take any positive value.

Comment: What about if we fix $z_1$ and also $z_2$. I am realizing that I do not need the requirement for all non-parallel vectors. Therefore $m$ is a solution for a fixed $z_1$ and $z_2$? So $m$ can be computed depending on $z_1$ and $z_2$.